# Positive linear functional $\phi\colon C(X)\to\mathbb{C}$ satisfies $|\phi(f)|\leq\phi(|f|)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, linear-transformations, operator-theory, absolute-value

Let $X$ be a compact (Hausdorff) space. Let $C(X)$ denote the linear space of continuous complex-valued functions on $X$. Suppose that $\phi\colon C(X)\to\mathbb{C}$ is a positive linear functional. Thus $\phi(f)\geq0$ whenever $f\geq0$. I want to prove that $$|\phi(f)|\leq\phi(|f|)$$ for all $f\in C(X)$. For real-valued $f$ this is easy. Indeed, decompose $f=f_{+}-f_{-}$, where $f_{+}:=\max(0,f)$ and $f_{-}:=\max(0,-f)$, and observe that $$|\phi(f)|=|\phi(f_{+})-\phi(f_{-})|\leq\phi(f_{+})+\phi(f_{-})=\phi(|f|).$$
But how do I prove this for complex-valued $f$?

Also, is there a method that doesn't require proving the real-valued case first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let us observe that the proof for the real-valued case can be obtained quite simply as follows: As $|f|-f \geq 0$ for real-valued $f$, and $\phi$ is positive, we have $\phi(|f|-f)\geq 0$, and hence $\phi(|f|)\geq \phi(f)$. Similarly,  $|f|+f \geq 0$, so $\phi(|f|)\geq - \phi(f)$. So, we have $\phi(|f|) \geq |\phi(f)|$.

Now for the complex-valued case: Note that the inequality you are trying to prove, is trivially true when $\phi(f)=0$, as $|f|$ is always a positive function. Assume that $\phi(f)\neq0$, and consider the complex number $\lambda := \frac{|\phi(f)|}{\phi(f)}$. Then,
$|\phi(f)|=\phi(\lambda f)=\frac{1}{2}(\phi(\lambda f)+\overline{\phi(\lambda f)})=\phi(\frac{\lambda f+\overline{\lambda f}}{2})=\phi(\Re(\lambda f))\leq \phi(|\lambda f|) = \phi(|f|)$

Above, I used the fact that $\phi(\lambda f)=\overline{\phi(\lambda f)}$, and I used $\Re(g)$ to denote the real part of the function $g$, which is equal to $\frac{g+\overline{g}}{2}$, and can easily be seen to be less that $|g|$, so $\phi(|g|)\geq|\phi(g)|$.

**Edit:** To clarify that $\phi$ indeed preserves adjoints:

Note that for real functions $f$, we have $f=f_+-f_-$, with $f_+$ and $f_-$ being positive functions (the decomposition you stated in the question itself). So $\phi(f_+)$ and $\phi(f_-)$ are positive, and $\phi(f)=\phi(f_+)-\phi(f_-)$ is real.

Now note that for any $f$, $f=\Re(f)+ i \Im(f)$, where $\Re(f)=\frac{f+\overline{f}}{2}$, $\Im(f)=\frac{f-\overline{f}}{2i}$ are real functions. Then, $\overline{\phi(f)}=\overline{(\phi(\Re(f))+ i \phi(\Im(f)))} = \overline{\phi(\Re(f))} - i (\overline{\phi(\Im(f))}) = \phi(\Re(f)) - i \phi(\Im(f)) = \phi(\Re(f) - i \Im(f)) = \phi(\overline{f})$.

Note that in the above line we have used that $\Re(f)$ and $\Im(f)$ are real functions, and that $\overline{f}=\Re(f)-i\Im(f)$

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have a question. Why do we have $\phi(f)=|\phi(f)|$ for real-valued $f$?

Comment: @QuantumSpace , thanks for pointing this out: you are indeed correct, I was mistaken, the initial statement was true for positive $f$ only. I have edited it accordingly.

Comment: @Calculix , I have edited it to correct the error. Please let me know if this is clear now.

Comment: @QuantumSpace , Thanks! This is actually based on a class of techniques I came across in Mrinal Ragupathi's solutions to exercises from Paulsen's text on "Completely Bounded Maps and Operator Algebras". You might be already familiar with Paulsen's text, here is the link to Ragupathi's solutions, on Paulsen's webpage:  https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~vpaulsen/cbmoa-solns.pdf

Comment: @UjanChakraborty I'm actually reading Paulsen's book at this very moment!

Comment: Why does $\phi$ preserve conjugation, i.e. $\overline{\phi(\lambda f)}=\phi(\overline{\lambda f})$?

Comment: @Calculix , since it preserves positivity, it also preserves hermiticity / self-adjointness (you can always write down a self-adjoint element as a difference of two positive elements: you already showed this in the question). Now, using the decomposition of any element f as linear combination of two hermitian elements in the form (Re(f)+i Im(f)), you can show that conjugation is preserved. Please let me know if this is clear.

Comment: @Calculix , in case it is not clear, I am editing the answer now, adding the details of this last question you asked.

Comment: @Calculix I have added this in the edits. Please let me know if this is clear now.

Comment: @UjanChakraborty It is very clear! Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

By scaling, we may assume that $\phi$ is a state. Then, use the Riesz-Kakutani theorem that says that if $\phi \in C(X)^*$ is a state, there is a unique Radon probability measure $\mu$ such that
$$\phi(f) = \int_X f d\mu$$
for all $f \in C(X)$. Then, simply observe that
$$|\phi(f)| \le \int_X |f|d \mu = \phi(|f|)$$
and we are done.